# the best way to pass initial state with configureStore after migration from react-redux to redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

the scenario is when the user log in, i store his userInfo in localstorage, to avoid losing the session when i refresh the page,
this is my previous code in Store.js with react-redux

```
// import

const reducer = combineReducers({
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  // more reducers
})

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,  // i used to pass initial state (with userInfo in it) whith createStore
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store
```

this code used to work well for me, when i refresh the page i don't lose my session

and now i'm trying to migrate to redux-toolkit (i'll not change my old reducers, i"ll use the new way of code using createSlice with new ones only)

```
// import

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
}

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userLogin: userLoginReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
    userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
    // more reducers
  },
  initialState, // i don't know if this way is correct to add initial state to configureStore, it doesn't work
})

export default store
```

configureStore works well in my app with all reducers

- except the fact that i can't pass userInfo from localstorage to the initialState of userLogin to keep it populated to avoid losing the session when i refresh the page
  (NB: in my components i check if there's any data in userLogin ? if true nothing happens : if false user is sent to Login page

Comment: Anyone to help ?

Answer (score 11):

You add the [preloadedState](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#preloadedstate) property:

```js
// import

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
}

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userLogin: userLoginReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
    userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
    // more reducers
  },
  preloadedState: initialState,
})

export default store
```

Comment: this is not so smart. consider when you have multiple modules for initialState, there will have to be extra steps to put them together...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can set initial state as a 2nd parameter in configureStore(). However, you can create a createSlice() method with your initial state and reducers(action.type).

```
const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
}
```

After setting your initial state you can:

```
const userInfoSlice = createSlice({
      name: "userInfo",
      initialState: initialState,
      reducers: {
         yourReducerFunction(){ 
             //You can manipulate the state in here 
           }
        },
      },
    });
```

Then you can simply include them in configure store. Make sure they key is named reducer and also include .reducer at the end of your createSlice variable.

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: counterSlice.reducer,
});
```